# openlayers coordinate format to longitude, latitude (decimal)

Tags: geolocation, openlayers, geocoding

I get from webservice coordinates that are placed in Openlayers format??

The coordinates looks like (in the netherlands):

```
    X = 217382.52712700056
    Y = 576653.00667405012
```

I would like to convert them to Longitude/Latitude (decimal format) something like 5.34343, 51.34356

I thought it was in a format Spherical Mercator Meters. And I used this formule to convert it. But the result make no sense.

```
Dim mercX As Double = 217382.52712700056
Dim mercY As Double = 576653.00667405012
Dim rMajor As Integer = 6378137
Dim shift As Double = Math.PI * rMajor
Dim lon As Double = mercX / shift * 180.0
Dim lat As Double = mercY / shift * 180.0
lat = 180 / Math.PI * (2 * Math.Atan(Math.Exp(lat * Math.PI / 180.0)) - Math.PI / 2.0)
```

Hopefully someone can help me further....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those values come from OpenLayers (I assume that you get them from some basemaps like google or bing, so spherical mercator ones), they should be in meters based on EPSG:900913 (or EPSG:3857).In any case, it would be good to know how you got those values. I tried this web:

```
http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/
```

but the output is:

```
longitude = 1.95278046619
latitude = 5.17311926477
```

which has no sense either. I attached a image to show you what I did.

Hope this helps,

[image]